# Flux of $F(x,y,z) = (zy^2-2x,\frac{1}{4}yz+z^2,xy+2x^2+2z)$ exiting from $\Omega$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the flux of the vector field

$$F(x,y,z) = (zy^2-2x,\frac{1}{4}yz+z^2,xy+2x^2+2z)$$

exiting from $\Omega = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 16, z \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\}$.

This is what I have done so far: I calculated $\mathrm{div}(F) = \frac{1}{4}z$.
Then I tried this integral:

$$ \frac{1}{4}\iiint_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}zdz $$
$$ \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{8}} \rho^3 d\rho d\theta$$

Then, this sums up to $4\pi$. However the result should be 8$\pi$. Is there some problem with my reasoning?

Comment: Are you sure it is $z \le \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ and not $z \ge \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @toliveira Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spherical coordinates:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi} \int_0^{4} \frac{\rho \cos \phi}{4} \rho^2 \sin \phi \;d\rho d\phi d \theta = -\frac{1}{16} \times 2\pi \times 4^3 = -8 \pi
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? I do not understand why that is the boundary of $\phi$, shouldn't it be: ($\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$) U ($\frac{7\pi}{4}$,$2\pi$)

Comment: By definition, $0\le \phi \le \pi$.  $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is equivalent to $\phi=\pi/4$. If you draw the projection of the solid in the $yz$ plane, you will have an upside down "PacMan". To include all points of the PacMan, you need to consider $\phi$ all the way up to its upper bound, $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate the integral in cylindrical coordinates:
$$\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{4} \int_{z=-\sqrt{16-r^2}}^{r\cos(\varphi)} \frac{1}{4}z r\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\varphi=-8\pi $$
At first I did decompose the complete volume into two volumes and afterwards I found out that the integration limit for $z$ is continuous.

The other way in spherical coordinates would be
$$\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\vartheta=-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{r=0}^{4} \frac{r\sin(\vartheta)}{4}r^2\cos(\vartheta)\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\vartheta\mathrm{d}\varphi=-8\pi.$$